PKIX validity check failed error API Gateway-NLB-Ip address
I have a problem with my infrastructure.
I have configured a VPC link on AWS with a network load balancer to handle API calls made to my API Gateway and sent to on-premise backends via IP address.
Specifically, I currently have all TLS listeners with TLS target groups and a certificate for each backend (backend works on 443 port with HTTPS)
I tried using the TCP protocol for the listener and target group to avoid using certificates, as the client does not want to issue more, but I get the following error:
Execution failed due to configuration error: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
By analyzing the following links,
API Gateway error
I believe I understood that TLS is necessary because termination would happen on the NLB and then the unencrypted traffic would be forwarded to the on-premise backends that use HTTPS.
My question are:
How can I confirm this thesis and provide a justification for using certificates on the network load balancer to the client?
Is possible to use TCP protocol to communicate with be on premises and resolve the issue? I have already set the insecureSkipVerification:true and we need to use also the TLS protocol.
I hope my questions are clear, thanks
